# Extension of the Gershgorin circle theorem for symmetric matrices and localization of positive eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, gershgorin-sets

In mathematics, the Gershgorin circle theorem can be used to localize eigenvalues of a matrix (including symmetric). Let $A$ be a real symmetry $n × n$ matrix, with entries $a_{ij}$. For $i∈{1,…,n}$  let $R_i$ be the sum of the absolute values of the non-diagonal entries in the $i$-th row:

$R_{i}=\sum _{j\neq {i}}\left|a_{ij}\right|$

Let $D(a_{ii},R_{i})\subseteq \mathbb {C}$ be a closed disc centered at $a_{ii}$ with radius $R_{i}$. Such a disc is called a Gershgorin disc.

**Theorem:** Every eigenvalue of $A$ lies within at least one of the Gershgorin discs $D(a_{ii},R_{i}).$

I was interested in the case when the center of the circle closest to the imaginary axis is in the right half-plane, but part of the circle also intersects the negative half-plane. In this case, the eigenvalue of the matrix may be negative, but satisfies the Gershgorin circle theorem.

[image]

**Problem:** What condition can be added to the Gershgorin theorem so that the eigenvalues localized with its help always lie only in the right half-plane, i.e. were only positive? This condition should also make it work in cases where the circle may slightly touch the left half-plane.

Comment: If all entries of the matrix are positive, then the eigenvalue with largest absolute value is positive, see [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

Comment: If the matrix is positive-definite, then all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: @user376343 is there a lower bound for the smallest eigenvalue in a similar way?

Comment: the smallest eigenvalue is the reciprocal of the largest one. You can find an upper bound of the latest, then its reciprocal will be a lower bound of the smallest eigenvalue. All this holds under the assumption that the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: @user376343 Is it possible to choose the coefficients of the matrix in such a way that it is positive definite, using the Gershgorin theorem and the facts that you have voiced? I understand that this is a matrix-completion task and is NP-complete. However, if I know some of the elements of the matrix and the constraints on others, is it possible to solve such a problem using Gershgorin circles? The matrix should be composed in such a way as to take into account the cases shown in my picture in the topic

Comment: @user376343 Does this theorem only apply to matrices with positive entries? If so, then this is a colossal shortcoming of this theorem. Because I work with matrices that have negative elements.

Comment: Gerschgorin circle theorem is universal, the matrices can even be complex.

Comment: @user376343 I am about Perron-Frobenius theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem is valid for matrices with positive entries and for some matrices with non-negative entries.